# What is known about $x^m + y^m = z^n$ over $\mathbb{N}$ when $m,n \geq 2$ and $m \neq n$?

Tags: number-theory

So Fermat's Last Theorem resolves the question of positive integer solutions to $x^m + y^m = z^n$ when $m = n \geq 3$. But what about if $m \neq n$ and $m,n \geq 2$? Is anything general known about when there are positive integer solutions? Clearly if $gcd(m,n) \geq 3$ then there are no solutions by Fermat's Last Theorem. So let's assume $gcd(m,n) \leq 2$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal's_conjecture

Answer (score 4):

Suppose for example that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Let $x=y=2^s$ and $z=2^t$. Then our equation becomes $2^{1+sm}=2^{tn}$.

There are infinitely many pairs of positive integers $(s,t)$ such that $1+sm=tn$, so the equation $x^m+y^m=z^n$ has infinitely many positive (but uninteresting!) solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Equation of the form

$$x^p + y^q = z^r\quad\text{ where }\quad x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}\;\;\text{ and }\;\; p, q, r \ge 2,\; \max(p,q,r) > 2$$

is called super-Fermat equation. A solution of it is called trivial if $xyz = 0$ or $\pm 1$ and called primitive if $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$.

For the equation at hand

$$x^m + y^m = z^n \quad\text{ where }\quad m, n \ge 2, m \ne n, \gcd(m,n) \le 2$$

Following is a summary of what I know:

- $x^3 + y^3 = z^2$

  There are infinitely many primitive solutions falling into 3 infinite families.
  One infinite family is given by the parametrization:
  $$\begin{cases}
  x &= u(u^3 − 8v^3),\\
  y &= 4v(u^3 + v^3),\\ 
  z &= u^6 + 20u^3v^3 − 8v^6
  \end{cases}$$
  subject to the constraint $3 \not| u + v$, $2 \not| u$ and $\gcd(u,v) = 1$.
- $x^m + y^m = z^2$ for $m > 3$.

  There is no non-trivial primitive solution. See the paper [Winding quotients and some variants of Fermat’s Last Theorem](https://www.imj-prg.fr/~loic.merel/winding.pdf) 
  by Darmon and Merel for a proof.
- $x^2 + y^2 = z^n$ for $n \ge 3$.

  There are infinitely many primitive solutions. In particular, given any two positive integers $s,t$ one even, one odd, co-prime with each other. If we define  $x,y,z$ by

  $$x + i y = (s + it)^n \quad\text{ AND }\quad z = (s^2+t^2)$$
  then $x,y,z$ will be a primitive solution.
- Otherwise, $m \ne n$ and  $m, n \ge 3 \implies 1/m + 1/m + 1/n < 1$.

  It is known that if we assume [abc conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture), then the total number of non trivial primitive solutions for
  $$x^p \pm y^q \pm z^r = 0\quad\text{ with }\quad 1/p + 1/q + 1/r < 1\tag{*1}$$
  is finite, even allowing $p, q, r$ to vary. Here, if $x = \pm 1$ (respectively $y = \pm 1$ or $z = \pm 1$), we identify solutions having the same value of $x^p$ (respectively $y^q$ or $z^r$)

  As of this moment, there are essentially only 10 known solutions for $(*1)$:
  $$\begin{array}{rcll}
  1^p + 2^3 &=& (\pm 3)^2  &\text{ for $p \ge 7$, and $(-1)^p$ when $p$ is even}\\
  (\pm 3)^4 + (-2)^5 &=& (\pm 7)^2\\
  2^9 + (-7)^3 &=& (\pm 13)^2\\
  2^7 + 17^3 &=& (\pm 71)^2\\
  3^5 + (\pm 11)^4 &=& (\pm 122)^2\\
  15613^3 - (\pm33)^8 &=& (\pm1549034)^2\\
  65^7 + (-1414)^3 &=& (\pm 2213459)^2\\
  113^7 + (-9262)^3 &=& (\pm 15312283)^2\\
  17^7 + 76271^3 &=& (\pm 21063928)^2\\
  (\pm 43)^8 + 96222^3 &=& (\pm 30042907)^2
  \end{array}$$
  Since all these known solutions has at least one of $p, q, r$ equal to $2$, this means
  there are no known non-trivial primitive solutions when both $m, n \ge 3$.

Most of the material in this post is extracted from Chapter 14, *The super-Fermat equation* of the book [Number Theory, Vol II: Analytic and Modern Tools](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387498931) by H. Cohen. If you want more details, please consult the book directly.

Answer (score 0):

Some can and formula writing.

$$X^2+Y^2=Z^4$$

Solutions have the form:

$$X=4ps(p^2-s^2)$$

$$Y=p^4-6p^2s^2+s^4$$

$$Z=p^2+s^2$$

$p,s$ - integers.

Can all make it easier to prove that the equation:

$$X^2+Y^2=Z^n$$

It is enough to write the formula generates an endless series of decisions in all degrees.

For this we use the Pythagorean triple. And the number of their sets.

$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

$$a=2ps$$

$$b=p^2-s^2$$

$$c=p^2+s^2$$

$p,s$ - what some integers.  Then the solution can be written.

$$X=2psc^{n-1}$$

$$Y=(p^2-s^2)c^{n-1}$$

$$Z=c^2$$

So there is always a solution.

In the equation: $$X^2+Y^2=qZ^3$$

If the ratio is such that the root of an integer: $c=\sqrt{q-1}$

Then the solution is:

$$X=-2(c+1)p^6+4(2c(q-2)-3q)p^5s+2(c(5q^2-2q-8)-q^2-22q+8)p^4s^2+$$

$$+8q(5q^2-14q+4)p^3s^3+2(c(5q^2-2q-8)+q^2+22q-8)q(q-2)p^2s^4-$$

$$-4(2c(q-2)+3q)q^2(q-2)^2ps^5-2(c-1)q^3(q-2)^3s^6$$

...........................................................................................................................................................

$$Y=2(c-1)p^6+4(2qc+q-4)p^5s+2(c(-5q^2+18q-8)+15q^2-22q-8)p^4s^2+$$

$$+8q(q^2+6q-12)p^3s^3-2(c(5q^2-18q+8)+15q^2-22q-8)q(q-2)p^2s^4-$$

$$-4(2qc-q+4)q^2(q-2)^2ps^5+2(c+1)q^3(q-2)^3s^6$$

............................................................................................................................................................

$$Z=2p^4+8p^3s+4(q^2-2q+4)p^2s^2-8q(q-2)ps^3+2q^2(q-2)^2s^4$$

And more.

$$X=-2(c-1)p^6-4(2c(q-2)+3q)p^5s+2(c(5q^2-2q-8)+q^2+22q-8)p^4s^2+$$

$$+8q(5q^2-14q+4)p^3s^3+2(c(5q^2-2q-8)-q^2-22q+8)q(q-2)p^2s^4+$$

$$+4(2c(q-2)-3q)q^2(q-2)^2ps^5-2(c+1)q^3(q-2)^3s^6$$

.............................................................................................................................................................

$$Y=2(c+1)p^6-4(2qc-q+4)p^5s+2(c(-5q^2+18q-8)-15q^2+22q+8)p^4s^2+$$

$$+8q(q^2+6q-12)p^3s^3+2(c(-5q^2+18q-8)+15q^2-22q-8)q(q-2)p^2s^4+$$

$$+4(2qc+q-4)q^2(q-2)^2ps^5+2(c-1)q^3(q-2)^3s^6$$

.............................................................................................................................................................

$$Z=2p^4-8p^3s+4(q^2-2q+4)p^2s^2+8q(q-2)ps^3+2q^2(q-2)^2s^4$$

Well you can and draw another formula.  $$x^3+y^3=z^2$$

$$x=(b^2-a^2)(b^2+2ba-2a^2)c^2$$

$$y=(b^2-a^2)(2b^2-2ab-a^2)c^2$$

$$z=3(b^2-a^2)^2(a^2-ab+b^2)c^3$$

The most interesting thing there is that the formula that led, like should not give mutually simple solutions, but after sokrasheniya on common divisor can be obtained and are relatively prime solutions. This means that the formula itself describes as relatively prime so no. Coprime solutions - there are private solutions.

the equation:    $$(X+1)^3-X^3=Y^2$$

Solutions can be written if we use the solutions of Pell's equation:  $p^2-3s^2=1$
Then the solution can be written:

$$X=\pm2ps-p^2$$

$$Y=p^2\mp3ps+3s^2$$

If we make the change:

$$q=2ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$

$$t=4ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$

Then the solutions are of the form:

$$Y=t^2-tq+q^2$$

$$X=t(t-2q)$$

If we make the change:

$$t=3ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$

$$q=4ps\pm(p^2+3s^2)$$

Then the solutions are of the form:

$$X=-4t(t+q)$$

$$Y=4t^2+6tq+3q^2$$

the equation:

$$X^2+Y^2=Z^3$$

Has the solutions:

$$X=2k^6+8tk^5+2(7t^2+8qt-9q^2)k^4+16(t^3+2qt^2-tq^2-2q^3)k^3+$$

$$+2(7t^4+12qt^3+6q^2t^2-28tq^3-9q^4)k^2+8(t^5+2qt^4-2q^3t^2-5tq^4)k+$$

$$+2(q^6-4tq^5-5q^4t^2-5q^2t^4+4qt^5+t^6)$$

.................................................................................................................................................

$$Y=2k^6+4(3q+t)k^5+2(9q^2+16qt+t^2)k^4+32qt(2q+t)k^3+$$

$$+2(-9q^4+20tq^3+30q^2t^2+12qt^3-t^4)k^2+$$

$$+4(-3q^5-tq^4+10q^3t^2+6q^2t^3+5qt^4-t^5)k-$$

$$-2(q^6+4tq^5-5q^4t^2-5q^2t^4-4qt^5+t^6)$$

.................................................................................................................................................

$$Z=2k^4+4(q+t)k^3+4(q+t)^2k^2+4(q^3+tq^2+qt^2+t^3)k+2(q^2+t^2)^2$$

$q,t,k$ - What are some integers any sign.  After substituting the numbers and get a result it will be necessary to divide by the greatest common divisor. This is to obtain the primitive solutions.

I think until formula will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I attempt to solve the equation $x^3+y^3=z^n, x,y,z, n\in N \textrm{  and }n>3.$

Noting that $(1,1,2,1)$ is a solution and multiplying it by $2^{3k}$, we have
$$1^3+1^3=2^1 \Rightarrow \left(2^k\right)^{3 }+\left(2^k\right)^3=2^{3 k+1}$$
Therefore there are infinitely many solutions
$$(2^k,2^k, 2,3 k+1),$$
where $k\in N.$

---

Also $(1,2,3,2)$ is a solution and multiplying it by $3^{3k}$, we have
$$1^3+2^3=3^2 \Rightarrow (3^k)^{3 }+\left(2 \cdot 3^k\right)^3=3^{3 k+2}$$
Therefore there are infinitely many solutions
$$(3^k,2(3^k), 3,3 k+2) \textrm{ or } (2(3^k) ,3^k, 3,3 k+2), $$ where $k\in N.$