# If $a,b > 1$ and $r>2$ does $ax^2+by^2=z^r$ have any rational solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have been trying to solve the following equation for months without much success. It has been so far a very frustrating endeavor.Please help.

Consider the diophantine equation: $x^2+y^2=z^r$ where $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ and $r>2$.
Assuming that there exists a non-trivial triplet: $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ satisfying: $$x_0^2+y_0^2=z_0^r$$ How do I find the parametrization of:$$ax^2+by^2=z^r$$?

Comment: Do you expect that knowing, e.g. $2^2 + 11^2 = 5^3$, will allow us to parameterize integer solutions to $ax^2 + by^2 = z^3$?

Comment: @hardmath, Maybe... The same way that knowing the pythagoras triples $$ x=U^2-V^2$$ $$ y=2UV$$ $$z=U^2+V^2$$ and a primitive non-zero solution: $$ (x_0,y_0,z_0)$$ allow us to parametrize the equation: $ax^2+by^2=cz^2$.

Comment: I don't know, but there are some Community members who often surprise me with their intimate knowledge of parameterized Diophantine solutions.  Hopefully one of them will weigh in on your Question!

Comment: i sincerely hope so.

Comment: This is not a correct statement of the problem. It is necessary to establish precisely the extent $z^{r}$ and to solve a specific equation. Although some decisions can be recorded.    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966839/what-is-known-about-xm-ym-zn-over-mathbbn-when-m-n-geq-2-and-m/967575#967575

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to parameterize,

$$\color{red}ax^2+\color{red}by^2 =z^k$$

**for odd $k$**. Assume,

$$x^2+by^2 = (p^2+bq^2)^k$$

$$(x+y\sqrt{-b})(x-y\sqrt{-b}) = (p+q\sqrt{-b})^k(p-q\sqrt{-b})^k$$

Equate factors and solve for $x,y$. Hence,

$$x =\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2},\quad y = \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2\sqrt{-b}},\quad\text{where}\quad \alpha = (p+q\sqrt{-b})^k,\quad \beta = (p-q\sqrt{-b})^k$$

For example, let $k = 3$. Then,

$$(p (p^2 - 3 b q^2))^2 + b(3 p^2q - b q^3)^2 = (p^2+b q^2)^3$$

Let $p = \sqrt{a}p$. Then,

$$\color{red}a(ap^2 - 3 b q^2)^2 + \color{red}b(3 ap^2q - b q^3)^2 = (ap^2+b q^2)^3\tag{k=3}$$

for ***free*** variables $p,q$. Let $k = 5$,

$\color{red}a(a^2p^4 - 10 a b p^2q^2 + 5 b^2 q^4)^2 + \color{red}b(5 a^2p^4q - 10 a bp^2 q^3 + b^2 q^5)^2 = (ap^2+b q^2)^5\tag{k=5}$

and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot @Tito Piezas III. I saw a similar approach on your web page but I was unable to decipher it. Does that go to say that there is no solutions for $k >2$pair

Comment: You mean even $k$? There are no general formulas for $ax^2+by^2=z^2$ since there are certain integer $a,b$ such that  $x,y$ cannot be solved in positive integers. For example, $2x^2+3y^2=z^2$. However, there are _particular_ formulas. For example, $2x^2+7y^2=z^k$ is solvable in positive integers for any positive integer $k$.

Comment: For the special case $a+b = t^2$, here's a nice formula for $$ap^2+bq^2 = r^2$$ as, $$p = ae^2+f^2-2eft$$ $$q = ae^2-f^2$$ By plugging this $p,q$ into the formulas in main answer above, you can also solve $ap^2+bq^2 = r^k$ for $k = 2,6,10,14\dots$