# Prove that there exists infinite solutions for this Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Prove that the Diophantine equation $$x^4+y^3=z^2$$ has infinitely many primitive solutions.

My work:

We can re-write the equation as $$y^3=z^2-x^4$$ or $$y^3=(z+x^2)(z-x^2)$$

Now if $|z|>x^2$ then $b$ has to be positive otherwise $b$ will be negative. How to approach after that$?$ What to do if we have to prove infinite solutions of a equation$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is generalised Fermat, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456308/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-solutions-x-y-z-in-mathbb-n-of-the-foll?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966839/what-is-known-about-xm-ym-zn-over-mathbbn-when-m-n-geq-2-and-m). Since $1/2+1/3+1/4>1$, we have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde can you enlighten me a little .....i am not able to understand your last point...how is that coming into picture$?$

Comment: also power there was $7$

Comment: @DietrichBurde i only came to know that this equation is a super Fermat equation but it doesn't say about infinite solutions

Comment: Consider $y = 0$. This gives $x^4 = z^2$. This means that the general solutions are of the form $(x, 0, \pm x^2)$. notice that there are infinitely many of these. I'm not sure if this is legitimate, so I'm making this a comment.

Comment: @Hersh nice..... what if $y\neq0$ will it have infinite solutions in that case also$?$

Comment: Well I don't know about that case, but we still have infinitely many solns.

Comment: @Hersh you missed the key term *primitive*: the task is to show there are infinitely many primitive solutions.  A solution is called primitive when $x, y$ and $z$ have no common factor bigger than $1$. Your solutions $(x,0,\pm x^2)$ are not primitive when $|x| > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so we are on the same page we note that "OP" requested solution for, $(x^4+y^3=z^2)$ & @Dietrich Burde" provided link for equation, $(m^2+n^3=w^4)$ which are both not the same. Anyway no harm done. There is parametric solution for the below eqn:

$x^4+y^3=z^2$

$x=p^2q(2k-3)$

$y=p^3q^2$

$z=p^4q^2(k-1)(5k-7)$

Fo, $k=3$ we have,

$735^4+8575^3=960400^2$

Comment: The link in my answer is for all spherical cases, by the way (and has references for parametrizations). But of course, your parametrisation here is very useful for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Infinitely many relatively prime solutions are listed [here](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaseap/papers/bealconj.pdf) in section $4.1$, for the generalised Fermat equation
$$
x^p+y^q=z^r
$$
for the case
$$
\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}>1,
$$
the so-called *spherical case*, where we may assume that
$(p,q,r)=(2,2,r), (2,q,2), (2,3,3), (2,3,4), (2,4,3), (2,3,5)$. Here we have
$$
(p,q,r)=(2,3,4).
$$
A parametrisation for this case is given in the above article as
\begin{align*}
x & = 4ts(s^2 − 3t^2)(s^4 + 6t^2s^2 + 81t^4)(3s^4 + 2t^2s^2 + 3t^4),\\
 y & = ±(s^2 + 3t^2)(s^4 − 18t^2s^2 + 9t^4),\\
z & = (s^4 −2t^2s^2 +9t^4)(s^4 +30t^2s^2 +9t^4)
\end{align*}
for $s\not\equiv t\bmod 2$ and $3\nmid s$, and also for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Part (2) of my answer:

I tried editing my answer but it would not go through.

The missing info is:

$p=k^2-2$

$q=3k-4$

---